# C++ Write a program that prompts the user to enter a person's date of birth in numeric form (Throw/Catch)

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, struct, try-catch

I have written a code already, and it's a little tricky. I'm trying to get it to where the user writes their date of birth (ex: 12/05/1990) and it outputs their birth as ("December 5, 1990). I have already written the else/ifs for invalid Months and invalid Days. I'm for some reason not being able to get the day and year to display. For example; it's only displaying correctly the month which is  "December" and I'm getting a bunch of numbers for both Day and Year which are completely wrong. Also, any ideas of I should do for the program to be able to handle LEAP YEARS, for every 4 years. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct invalidDay : public exception 
{
const char * what() const throw () 
{
    return "Invalid date, try again.";
}
};

struct invalidMonth : public exception 
{
const char * what() const throw () 
{
    return "Invalid month, try again.";
}
};

int main()
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
string monthName;

try 
{
    cout << "Enter birthday: mm/dd/yyyy : ";
    cin >>month>>day>>year;

    if (day > 31)
        throw invalidDay();

    if (month == 1) {
        monthName = "January";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 2) {
        monthName = "February";
        if (day > 28)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 3) {
        monthName = "March";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 4) {
        monthName = "April";
        if (day > 30)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 5) {
        monthName = "May";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 6) {
        monthName = "June";
        if (day > 30)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 7) {
        monthName = "July";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 8) {
        monthName = "August";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 9) {
        monthName = "September";
        if (day > 30)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 10) {
        monthName = "October";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 11) {
        monthName = "Noveber";
        if (day > 30)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month == 12) {
        monthName = "December";
        if (day > 31)
            throw invalidDay();
    }
    else if (month > 12)
        throw invalidMonth();

    cout << monthName << " " << day << "," << year << "." << endl;


}

catch (invalidDay& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
catch (invalidMonth& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;



}
```

Comment: February may or may not have 28 days. Sometimes it has 29. Also remember the C++ `switch` statement which is great for breaking out things like this, though as you're also needing a lookup table, a `std::vector` of some month struct or tuple would help organize all of this better. Don't bang out dozens of lines of repeating code. Write a loop that operates on data.

Comment: If your input format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, there is no code to break the input string into month, day and year. Read the whole line as input and break it on `/` to get the m, d and y.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator in this case only stops reading normally when it encounters whitespace. When you try to read in the month, the operator hits the `/` character and raises the error flag in the stream since that character is neither part of the integer nor whitespace. After the error flag is raised, the two read operations that follow do nothing, leaving `day` and `year` uninitialized.

Use `std::getline()` to separate the parts of the input string, and parse them with `std::stoi()`.

Leap years can be dealt with easily by adding a check in your `if` statements that check if the year is a leap year and using a separate condition for that case when you check if the day is valid.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, you can use `std::getline`. After that you can use `std::substr` to split the dates and parse them to an int.

Example:

```
string temp;

cout << "Enter birthday: mm/dd/yyyy : ";
getline(cin, temp);

month = stoi(temp.substr(0, 2));
day = stoi(temp.substr(3,5));
year = stoi(temp.substr(6,10));
```

Input:

```
Enter birthday: mm/dd/yyyy : 05/24/2000
```

Output:

```
May 24,2000.
```